# How to save an image in a QGraphicsView into a bmp/jpg

Tags: qt, qt4

I am a newbie for Qt.
The question is that: After turning an image into the QGraphicsView, I use a qrubberband to select the cropping area of the image. It is successful to select the croppping region at the moment.But I don't know how to save that cropping region into a jpg/bmp afterwards. Note that I made an ui component for the GraphicsView called CGraphicsView.

```
void CGraphicsView::mousePressEvent
    ( QMouseEvent* event)
{



 mypoint = event->pos();
 rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);//new rectangle band
 rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(mypoint, QSize()));
 rubberBand->show();


 }

 void CGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
    if (rubberBand)
 {
 rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(mypoint, event->pos()).normalized());//Area Bounding
 }
 }

 void CGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
  if (rubberBand)
  {
     QRect myRect(mypoint, event->pos());
     rubberBand->hide();// hide on mouse Release
     QImage copyImage;  //<= this Qimage hold nothing
     copyImage = copyImage.copy(myRect);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special method in Qt. It allows get screenshot of view.

```
QString fileName = "path";
QPixmap pixMap = QPixmap::grabWidget(graphicsView, rectRegion);
pixMap.save(fileName);
```

Save() method can save picture in different formats and with compression.

Also with grabWidget() method you can grab another widgets too. Moreover, this method take QRect as argument so you can create screenshot of region what you need.

Comment: This only works if there's 1:1 scaling on the scene view, and the view displays the entire scene. It is generally a bad idea to grab a widget for this purpose. This shouldn't need a view at all, all you need is the scene itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can save a part of your scene to an image like :

```
QPixmap pixmap=QPixmap(myRect.size());
QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName( this->parentWidget(), tr("Save As"), tr("image.png"));

    if( !filename.isEmpty() )
    {
        QPainter painter( &pixmap );
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        scene->render( &painter, pixmap.rect(),myRect, Qt::KeepAspectRatio );
        painter.end();

        pixmap.save(filename,"PNG");
    }
```

Comment: It shows that: error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'QRect' to 'QPixmap'  And the scene is not defined. scene->render( &painter, pixmap.rect(),myRect, Qt::KeepAspectRatio );

Comment: @user3217504 I have updated the answer. Note that `scene` is an instance of your `QGraphicsScene`. You should have one for your self.

Comment: I agree with Kuba Ober, rendering the scene is better approach and your answer is better. I can't accept your answer, but I upvoted it.